# angular 4, md2-datepicker reset value

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I use [md2-datepicker](https://github.com/Promact/md2/tree/master/src/lib/datepicker) with reactive form in my `webApp`, but I need to reset selected value.

Do anybody know how I can to do it?

I tried to do something like this, but it doesn't work for me. The last selected value dosn't reset.

```
handleDayClick(request: any) {
    this.request = new BookingRequest();
    this.request.checkIn = request.date.format();
    this.requestForm.setValue(this.request);
    this.openDialog();
}
```

also I have a model for my form:

```
export class BookingRequest {
    id?: number;
    comment: string = '';
    checkIn: string = null;
    checkOut: string = null;
    approved: boolean = false;
}
```

Comment: Why it doesn't reset?

Comment: I don't know. Maybe the value was saved in datepicker component for example..

Answer (score 0):

Use the class to reset the value.

```
export class BookingRequest {
    id: number = null;
    comment: string = '';
    checkIn: string = null;
    checkOut: string = null;
    approved: boolean = false;
}
```